# Visual Studio 2015 and Git/TFS: Sync-Page-Error: Object not found - no matching loose object

Tags: git, tfs, tfs-2015

I work with `VS 2015 Enterprise` on a branch of a git-repository that is pulled from my remote origin (`= TFS 2015`).
I can change and commit something successfully. In the moment I go to the `Sync`-area in the `Team Explorer` I see an error on top:

```
An error occurred. Detailed message: Object not found - no matching loose object (<a 40-character-id is here>)
```

...and I don´t see my local commit in the list "Outgoing Commits" where I expected it to be.

But within the PowerShell I can execute "`git push`" without problems.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue on another client machine by pulling the same git-repository from TFS? If you pull another git-repository from TFS on the same client machine, would you meet the same issue?

Answer (score 2):

I saw this message in VS 2015 professional when trying to switch back from a feature branch to the master branch. restarting VS fixed it.

Comment: i got this out of no where just being in master. also getting Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/master'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched. at the command line

Answer (score 0):

If you reproduce this issue on another client machine by pulling the same git-repository from TFS, you may need to have a new branch from the original.

If you have the same issue pull another git-repository from TFS on the same client machine, you may try to clean the cache file on your client machine: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0\Cache`, and try resetting settings and add-in settings (`devenv /ResetSettings`) and (`devenv /ResetSkipPkgs`), try rebuilding all templates (`devenv /setup`).

Answer (score 0):

Open the git command prompt from the team explorer action dropdown, which should open the git repository folder
Type the following command to resolve the issue.

git status to know the changes

or

git pull to retrieve & merge the remote changes in the local environment.

Microsoft extensions are now getting notorious to stop working in the middle of the development, can't do much about it.

Note: Thanks to the reviewers for reviewing the post & informing the simple changes needed. Being a newbie to this world makes me a little bit defensive. Thanks for the suggestions & notes.